# VB.NET System.Argument Exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, unhandled

i'm new in vb .net programming, I've been encounter the following error when I'm trying to connect my form button to MySql database that:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Keyword not supported.
I have been working to troubleshoot this error but I didn't succeeded. Thanks for any help you are kind enough to provide! Please see my code for the class below:

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

```
Dim connect As New MySqlConnection

Dim connecto As String = "Server=localhost; User Id=root; Password; Database=sist"
Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    connect.ConnectionString = connecto
    Try
        connect.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully")
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label4.Text = Date.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You don't do anything but connect and open the connection. Is that the right format for your connection string? (Side note - you should close the connection in a finally block)

Answer (score 1):

```
connect.ConnectionString = connecto
```

Your first line inside the Button1_Click sub references connect and connecto.  But those objects are outside the scope of the sub.  You could move the instantiation inside the sub and it would work.

So:

```
Dim connect As New MySqlConnection
Dim connecto As String = "Server=localhost; User Id=root; Password; Database=sist"
connect.ConnectionString = connecto
    Try
        connect.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully")
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Or Better Yet

```
Dim connecto As String = "Server=localhost; User Id=root; Password; Database=sist"

Using connect As New MySqlConnection(connecto)
        Try
            connect.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Using
```

Comment: still this error persist, any help plz.....here is my codes Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connect As New MySqlConnection
        Dim connecto As String = "Server=localhost; User Id=root; Password; Database=sist"
        connect.ConnectionString = connecto
        Try
            connect.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: Can't read that... try editing your original question and using the code formatter.  Also try giving Password a value.